# How can I automatically add intents to addRequestHandler

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Currently, you have to add intents manually by defining it in addRequestHandlers

```
Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
            .addRequestHandlers(
                LaunchRequestHandler
            )
```

But is there a way How can I do it automatically for example in the loop? My intents will be in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intents are inside an array then can do something like below,

```
    const intents = [
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    ByeIntentHandler,
    CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
    HelpIntentHandler,
    ErrorHandler
];

    let skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
      .addRequestHandlers(
        ...intents
      )
      .create();
```

Comment: I tried, but It is not working, getting error `TypeError: requestHandler.canHandle is not a function`